# Scroll Collection view cells in table view cell to a particular index position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have the below structure in my app

Table view -> Table Cell -> Collection View -> CollectionView cell

Table view has 10 cells , each table cell has 1 collection view , and the collection view has 20 cells horizontally.

After the data has been loaded , I want the all the collection views to start from index 10 and should be able to scroll back and forth afterwards. Where should make use `collectionView.scrollToItem()`  so that "all" collection views loads from that index.

Comment: You should do this when you dequeue the tableview cell, you setup the collection view and scroll it to the desired indexpath

Comment: @omarzl Perfect! thanks. it works.